# how can I add a list to existing json file?

Tags: php

I want to add a list to a json file if the list does not exist.

but when I try to use `array()` I'm getting `0 => 1=> 2=>` instead of a list of objects

```
$list = array(
    "Version" => "1.0"
);

$users = array(
    "Users" => array(
    "Username"=> "test",
    "Level"=> "10"
    )
);

if(!isset($list['Users'])) {
    array_push($list, $users);
    echo json_encode($list);
}
exit;
```

result

```
{"Version":"1.0","0":{"Users":{"Username":"test","Level":"10"}}}
```

but my result should be

`{"Version":"1.0","Users":[{"Username":"test","Level":"10"}]}`

I'm new at php. regarding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the new key `users` if it doesn't exist and then add elements to it, like this:

```
$list = array(
    "Version" => "1.0"
);

$users = array(
    "Users" => array(
    "Username"=> "test",
    "Level"=> "10"
    )
);

if(!isset($list['Users'])) $list['users']=[];

foreach( $users as $a ){
    $list['users'][]=$a;
}

echo json_encode( $list );
```

The output:

```
{"Version":"1.0","users":[{"Username":"test","Level":"10"}]}
```

Comment: well that works. php is a bit confusing. `$list['users']=[]` :D nevermind thanxs

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

You don't need array_push(). Just add the Array `$users['Users']` inside `$list`.
Note: I have changed to `array()` notation to `[]` notation.

```php
$list =[
    "Version" => "1.0"
];

$users = [
    'Users' => [
        'Username' => 'test',
        'Level' => '10'
    ]
];
    

if(!isset($list['Users'])) {
    $list['Users'][] = $users['Users'];
    echo json_encode($list);
}
exit;
```

Output:

```php
{"Version":"1.0","Users":[{"Username":"test","Level":"10"}]}
```